# How to display column name and set scrollbar to jtable?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable, jtableheader

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("select * from department");
table_1.setModel(buildTableModel(result));
```

method:

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }
    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }
    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Don't use a null layout!!! Read the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

I put a JScrollPane in jframe then use following code:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("select * from department");
JTable t=new JTable();
t.setModel(buildTableModel(result));
s1.setViewportView(t);
```

s1 is JScrollPane.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your `JTable` inside a `JScrollPane`, and add the resulting `JScrollPane` to your layout.

The sample code you provided does not show how you're adding the JTable to the JPanel or JFrame of your application.

Comment: So, you're doing a frame.getContentPane().add(table) somewhere. That needs to say frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table)).

Comment: can you say me how to do it

Comment: Whatever code you're using to create your frame - put that in the question and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: `can you say me how to do it  –` - Read the JTable API and you will find a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables`. Click on the link for an explanation of how a JTable works and for plenty of working examples.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi, Where did you `wrap the table inside a scrollpane` as was suggested? If you don't know how to do this then read the tutorial. It is full of examples not only for JTable bout for other Swing components as well.

Comment: Change this line: "contentPane.add(table_1);" to "contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table_1));" and remove the three lines starting with "scrollPane = new JScrollPane();" - they're not doing anything.

Comment: I told you how to find the tutorial in a previous comment. @David, I would remove my upvote if I could for spoon feeding the answer. Every answer/comment in the posting has had to be repeated twice because the OP did not take the time to read the answers.

Comment: camickr, just trying to help a guy out. But @samiey, camickr has a point. You'll need to play around with this on your own at this point. You have the right pieces.

Comment: @David `just trying to help a guy out`- I understand that, but the problem is your last suggestion messed up the program even more because nobody has read my initial comment under the original question. You can't just add a component directly to the frame as you suggested. It will have a size of (0, 0) because a layout manager is not being used. That is why I keep suggesting that people should read the tutorial to learn the basics and start with a working program.